# Format a Number, Exactly Two in Length?

Tags: javascript

I have an integer that is less then 100 and is printed to an HTML page with JavaScript.  How do I format the integer so that it is exactly two digits long? For example:

01
02
03
...
09
10
11
12
...

Comment: @Rudie: it's the second sentence, right?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

## Update

This answer was written in 2011. See [liubiantao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276909/110164) for the 2021 version.

### Original

```
function pad(d) {
    return (d < 10) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString();
}

pad(1);  // 01
pad(9);  // 09
pad(10); // 10
```

Comment: what if negative?

Comment: Great help. Saves lots of time.

Comment: This works nicely for hexadecimal as well with one simple change:     ```function pad(d) {
return (d < 16) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString();
}```

Answer (score 38):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```
String(number).padStart(2, '0')
```

Comment: ..only if you use ES2017.

Comment: cleanest answer

Answer (score 36):

```
String("0" + x).slice(-2);
```

where `x` is your number.

Comment: Props for brevity. I like how the length is parameterized so you can use it dynamically for higher order digit expansions.

Answer (score 11):

Just use the following short function to get the result you need:

```
function pad2(number) {
    return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A direct way to pad a number to the left in Javascript is to calculate the number of digits by log base 10.
For example:

```
function padLeft(positiveInteger, totalDigits) {
  var padding = "00000000000000";
  var rounding = 1.000000000001;
  var currentDigits = positiveInteger > 0 ? 1 + Math.floor(rounding * (Math.log(positiveInteger) / Math.LN10)) : 1;
  return (padding + positiveInteger).substr(padding.length - (totalDigits - currentDigits));
}
```

The rounding factor fixes the problem that there is no way to get an exact log of powers of 10, for example Math.log(1000) / Math.LN10 == 2.9999999999999996
Of course one should add validation of the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function leftFillNum(num, targetLength) {
  return num.toString().padStart(targetLength, '0');
}

console.log(leftFillNum(3,2)); // ==> returns '03'
console.log(leftFillNum(33,2)); // ==> returns '33'
console.log(leftFillNum(3,4)); // ==> returns '0003'
console.log(leftFillNum(33,5)); // ==> returns '00033'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Return a string padded
function FormatMe(n) {
   return (n<10) ? '0'+n : n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function padLeft(a, b) {
    var l = (a + '').length;
    if (l >= b) {
        return a + '';
    } else {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < b - l ;i++) {
            arr.push('0');
        }
        arr.push(a);
        return arr.join('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this function.

```
function pad(n, len) {
    let l = Math.floor(len)
    let sn = '' + n
    let snl = sn.length
    if(snl >= l) return sn
    return '0'.repeat(l - snl) + sn
}
```

Usage Example

```
pad(1, 1)    // ==> returns '1' (string type)
pad(384, 5)  // ==> returns '00384'
pad(384, 4.5)// ==> returns '0384'
pad(5555, 2) // ==> returns '5555'
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const threeDigit = num => num.toString().padStart(3 , '0');
```

The function converts a number to a string and then returns a three-digit version of the number

Answer (score 0):

### I use regex to format my time such as

const str = '12:5'

### const final = str.replace(/\d+/g, (match, offset, string) => match < 10 ? '0' + match : match)

output: 12:05

Comment: let result = time.replace(/\d+/g, (match, offset, string) =>
      Number(match) < 10 && (match[0] !== '0' || match === '0') ? '0' + match : match)

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of previous answer:

```js
var result = [...Array(12)].map((_, i) => zeroFill(i + 1, 2));

function zeroFill(num, size) {
  let s = num + '';
  while (s.length < size) s = `0${s}`;
  return s;
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

lodash has padStart, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#padStart

padStart(1, 2, '0')
it will pad 1 => 01, it wont take care of negative numbers, as - will be considered as padding

Answer (score 0):

Showing an example to ensure the length is 3 for every digit given up to 999, the code is self-explanatory and simple

```
            function formatter(d) {
              if (d < 1000) {
                if (d < 10) {
                  return `00${d}`;
                } else if (d < 100) {
                  return `0${d}`;
                } else {
                  return `${d}`;
                }
              } else {
                return `Enter valid number`;
              }
            }
```