# Support of 0 in the beginning of numbers in Odometer.js

Tags: javascript, odometer

I want to use odometer to show numbers in my html. Numbers vary from 100 to 10mn. I want to have a fixed number of digits. What is the format for that?

here is what I have been using:

```
  var total_ads1 = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "total_ads");


  od = new Odometer({
    el: document.querySelector(".total_ads"),
    value: sum,
    format:'(dd,ddd,ddd)',
    theme:'car',
    duration:1000,
  });
```

Every time it has to print smaller number it alters the number of cells in the odometer. I thought updating the inner html with text might work but it looks like it converts it internally to numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774042/format-a-number-exactly-two-in-length.

Comment: the whole problem is that even if I update the odometer by forcing innerHTML to be some text it converts it to number.

Comment: So set it in a way that after it updates, then you pad it again, or call your padding function after each update. `value: pad(sum)` is just as easy to utilize. Check out this question for more ideas on solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Comment: Value is just the number to start with and it is not taking 0s in that too. I guess there is no solution to that. It was not designed for padded numbers

Comment: Just for clarity, this question seems to be referencing the [Odometer.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/) library.

Answer (score 4):

Michael has posted a [compiled version of his workaround](https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer/pull/88/commits/b589e93ee8470417213706569ed472144d121f82)! Great job.
You can use it instead of the official version and specify in his script a Minimum Integer length:

```
MIN_INTEGER_LEN = 0;
```

Comment: If you are creating an Odometer object you can use: `new Odometer ({ minIntegerLen: 5 });`