# React Native - how to change format from 1 to 01 for wheel picker data

Tags: react-native

I've data for ReactNativeWheelPicker which looks like this:

```
const hoursData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

and than picker receives these data: `data={hoursData}`

I tried to use following method to convert e.g. 1 to 01:

```
(hoursData < 10 ? "0" + hoursData : hoursData)
```

Unfortunately, wherever I put this, wheel picker always shows single number. 
I'm using wheel picker from this repo: https://github.com/ElekenAgency/ReactNativeWheelPicker

Any suggestions would be appreciated ;)

EDIT (updated full code):

```
const hoursData = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];

class TimePickerMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedHours: 9,
    };
  }
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rowPicker}>
        <WheelPicker
           onItemSelected={ (event)=> this.setState({ index: event.position, selectedHours: event.data }) }
           isCurved
           isCyclic
           data={hoursData}
           style={styles.wheelPicker}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12247889/12831209](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12247889/12831209)
try this answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
    const hoursData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    const data = hoursData.map(data => {
      if (data < 10) {
        return '0' + data
      }
      return '' + data
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately this doesn't work ;(

Comment: can you show me the full code, cant understand what you want to do right now?

Comment: I think that I solved the problem. Just changed `hoursData` to look like this: `const hoursData = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']` and it seems to work ;)

Comment: I think the edited answer should also work now, since the array needs to be of type String.